# Flutter Help - Retrieving user properties from Stream

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, stream-builder

I retrieve the logged in user's Name based upon the uid from a stream called UserData. With this stream I can put the users name on the dashboard title. Ex. "Tom's Dashboard'.

I'm using stream builder in the dashboard page (below) to retrieve the name, but I receive the "getter 'uid' null" on logout because, I'm guessing, stream builder rebuilds.

Therefore, how else can I retrieve the name without using Stream Builder? I tried using "Provider.of(context)", but I also get an error about the stream being on another route.

Dashboard Page:

```
class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function toggleView;

  Dashboard({this.toggleView});
  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String currName;
  String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    return StreamBuilder(
        key: _formKey,
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            UserData userData = snapshot.data;
            currName = userData.name;
            if (currName == 'new member') {
              title = 'Dashboard';
            } else {
              title = currName; //+ "'s Dashboard";
            }
          }
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              title: Text('$title'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton.icon(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                  label: Text(''),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
                    await _auth.signOut();
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton.icon(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                  label: Text(''),
                  onPressed: () => _showSettingsPanel(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

UserData stream:

```
  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
        uid: uid,
        name: snapshot.data['name'],
        location: snapshot.data['location'],
        accountType: snapshot.data['accountType']);
  }

  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return userProfileCollection
        .document(uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

main.dart:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(value: AuthService().user,
    child: MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      //home: Login(),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => AuthLoading(),
        '/home': (context) => Login(),
        '/register': (context) => Register(),
        '/dashboard': (context) => Dashboard(),
      },
    ));
  }
}
```